# Pump to push inverter A/C dripping water?

Tags: water, air-conditioning, pump, central-air

I live on the top floor of the building and my bedroom has an inverter A/C that naturally drips water to the street. The bedroom has access to the roof.

Is there some inexpensive pump that will push this dripping water two feet up so that it goes to the rooftop?

I would connect this pump to the a/c drain on the outside of the building. The the pump would push the water to the roof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are all sorts of AC condensate pumps available that are  designed to pump condensate up and out of your house. You would probably be better off tubing the condensate from outside inside to the pump and then routing a tube to the roof. Google "condensate pumps" or check ebay.

What happens to the water when you pump it onto the roof?

Comment: The roof has several drains.